# Unable to locate package libQt5SerialPort5

Tags: package-management, locate

Currently i am using the ubuntu 12.04 LTS. However, i had this issue of locating the specific package 'libQt5SerialPort5'. Have tried the method using sudo -aptget install but still unable to find that particular package. Anyone mind helping me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The correct package is called libqt5serialport5. To install it use

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5serialport5
```

Comment: dear sir still unable to locate the package after correction.

Comment: The packages deb are available here ` http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qtserialport-opensource-src/'. You can manually download and install using `sudo dpkg -i libqt*`.